# How to test $ionicPopup.show

Tags: ionic-framework, jasmine

I have an ionicPopup like so:

```
    function editNotifications() {
        var popUp = $ionicPopup.show({
            template: '<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="item in vm.notifications" ng-model="item.notification" ng-checked="item.notification">' +
            '<span class="notificationsFont">{{item.settingsText}}</span></ion-checkbox>',
            title: 'Notification Settings',
            scope: $scope,
            buttons: [ 
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                onTap: function(e) {
                    vm.notifications = localStorageManager.get('notificationStatus');
                }
            },
            {
                text: '<b>Ok</b>',
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(e) {
                    localStorageManager.set('notificationStatus', vm.notifications);
                    vm.notificationText = "Notifications off";
                    setNotificationValuesBasedOnUserInput(vm.notifications);
                }

            }]
            });
    };
```

Here is what I have so far;

```
    it('Should edit notifications', function() {
        spyOn($ionicPopup, 'show').and.callFake(function() {
            return $q.resolve(true);
        })
        spyOn(localStorageManager, 'set');

        controller = createController();
        controller.editNotifications();
        $scope.$apply();

        expect(localStorageManager.set).toHaveBeenCalled();
        // expect(localStorageManager.set).toHaveBeenCalledWith('notificationStatus');
    });
```

I basically have no idea how to test this thing.  There doesn't seem to be much on the internet.  I would think I need to do something in my callFake function but I'm a bit stuck.  Anyone ever successfully tested this beast before?

Answer (score 0):

Go through this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52565500/7943457

And modify your code something like this:

```
function editNotifications() {
        var popUp = $ionicPopup.show({
            template: '<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="item in vm.notifications" ng-model="item.notification" ng-checked="item.notification">' +
            '<span class="notificationsFont">{{item.settingsText}}</span></ion-checkbox>',
            title: 'Notification Settings',
            scope: $scope,
            buttons: [ 
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                onTap: function(e) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            {
                text: '<b>Ok</b>',
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(e) {
                    return true;
                }

            }]
            });
            popup.then(function(response){
              if(response){ //when response is true
                 localStorageManager.set('notificationStatus', vm.notifications);
                 vm.notificationText = "Notifications off";
                 setNotificationValuesBasedOnUserInput(vm.notifications);
              }else{ //when response is false
                 vm.notifications = localStorageManager.get('notificationStatus');
              }
            })
    };
```

You can test it like this:

```
it('Should edit notifications', function() {
    spyOn($ionicPopup, 'show').and.callFake(function() {
        return $q.resolve(true);
    })
    spyOn(localStorageManager, 'set');

    controller = createController();
    controller.editNotifications();
    $scope.$apply();

    expect(localStorageManager.set).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // expect(localStorageManager.set).toHaveBeenCalledWith('notificationStatus');
});

it('Should get notifications', function() {
    spyOn($ionicPopup, 'show').and.callFake(function() {
       return $q.resolve(false);
    })
    spyOn(localStorageManager, 'get');

    controller = createController();
    controller.editNotifications();
    $scope.$apply();
    expect(localStorageManager.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
        // expect(localStorageManager.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('notificationStatus');
});
```

Hope it helps.